# Inserting nodes in Agensgraph through Python and cypher

Tags: python, cypher, agens-graph

In this example I am trying to add a new author node taking the variables from outside the cypher code. This method works on normal PostgreSQL code but I'm trying to get the syntax right to allow python to do it for me. I've imported pyscopg2 and agensgraph. The code works fine if the attributes are added manually. The following code returnds the error:

'str' object is not callable

```
    def newAuthor(self):
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Processing...')
    try:
        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=agens host=localhost user=agens password=pw port=5433")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("""SET graph_path = publications;""")


        name = 'Apel'
        firstName = 'Jan'
        lastName = 'Apel'
        initials = ''

        cur.execute("""
        CREATE (n:Author { name: %s, firstName: %s, lastName: %s, initials: %s })
        """(name, firstName, lastName, initials))


        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late answer and you found answer on your own.

Just wanna share my way to use cypher query in python. Hopefully this might be helpful someone in the future.

If you do not mind to bind the parameters with its order, you may use following way :

```
createCypher = "CREATE (n:Author {name : %s, firstName : %s, lastName : %s, initials : %s })"
name = "Apel"
firstName = "Jan"
lastName = "Apel"
initials = ""
cur.execute (createCypher, (name, firstName, lastName, initials, ))
```

However, if you want to specify the location of parameter with the key of dictation, I believe that building query string with format is the only way :

```
createCypher = "CREATE (n:SUBJECT {{name :'{name}', firstName: '{firstName}', lastName : '{lastName}', initials : '{initials}' }})"
param = {}
param["name"] = "Apel2"
param["firstName"] = "Jan2"
param["lastName"] = "Apel2"
param["initials"] = ""
cur.execute(createCypher2.format(**param))
```

Both work find for me.

Comment: I also suspect this is a safer way of doing things rather than using the '+' assignment, I'll test it out shortly! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue, is this the best way?

```
        name = 'Apel'
        firstName = 'Jan'
        lastName = 'Apel'
        initials = ''
        cypher = "CREATE (n:Author { name:  \'"   + name + "\', firstName: \'" + firstName + "\', lastName: \'" + lastName + "\', initials: \'" + initials + "\' })"
        cur.execute(cypher)
```